# Spring resource

Tags: spring, resources, web, javabeans

Problem: I want to make the below bean definitions (specified in aaplicationContext.xml) optional for "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener". If i am not providing the "emsPropLocation" context parameter correctly, tomcat web container is not able to initialized properly and it is obvious reason. Is there any way to make it optional?

**appicationContext.xml:**

```xml
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    <property name="location" value="file:/#{contextParameters.emsPropLocation}" />
  </bean>

  <!-- TIBCO Connection Factory Bean -->
  <bean id="tibcoConnectionFactory" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="${emsServerURL}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${emsUserName}"/>
    <property name="userPassword" value="${emsPassword}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptCount" value="${connAttemptCount}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptDelay" value="${connAttemptDelay}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptTimeout" value="${connAttemptTimeout}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptCount" value="${reconnAttemptCount}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptDelay" value="${reconnAttemptDelay}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptTimeout" value="${reconnAttemptTimeout}"/>
  </bean>


  <!-- bean id="tibcoUtil" class="com.nr.ns.upload.TibcoUtil" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="true"/>
  </bean-->

  <bean id="jmsExceptionListener" class="com.nr.ns.upload.LogMsgExceptionListener"/>

  <!-- Spring CachingConnectionFactory Bean -->
  <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="tibcoConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="${reconnectOnException}"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${sessionCacheSize}"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsExceptionListener"/>
  </bean> 

  <!-- JMSTemplate Bean -->
  <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${receiveTimeout}"/>
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="${deliveryMode}"/>
  </bean>
```

We are keeping WAR file outside tomcat and to make it happen we have "app.xml" file inside TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost.

**app.xml:**

```xml
<Context path="/app"
    docBase="/abc/ccp/app.war"
    reloadable="true"
    unpackWAR="false">

    <Parameter name="emsPropLocation"
        value="/xyz/config/EMSServerConf.properties"
        override="false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: How would you want it to behave?

Comment: If emsProplocation is not present in the context parameter, still it should work.

Comment: How?  What value should it take?

Comment: It will take the path of properties file which holds the EMS config properties.

Comment: You need to start being a bit more forthcoming if you want this problem solved.  How can your code work if you don't supply it with a value?  How can it meaningfully do anything if the value is missing?  You need to explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to make the properties file optional and the bean required the properties value defined as lazy-init="true" so the bean wouldn't be loaded on startup. By that way my application can run without fail if the properties file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

have a try to change the ignoreResourceNotFound property of your propertyConfigurer to true.

Answer (score 0):

If contextParameters.emsPropLocation is not set, this will default to what is afer the colon.

```
<property name="location" value="file:/#{contextParameters.emsPropLocation:/xyz/config/EMSServerConf.properties}" />
```